# How to split string into an associative array which has arrays within arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string: `names=bob;mike;sam&age=30;23;22&fav-nums=200;300;400`

I was wondering if there is a function which can split this into an associative array which as arrays within it. For example

```
Array (
    ["name"] => Array
                (
                    bob,
                    mike,
                    sam
                )
    ["age"] =>  Array
                (
                    30,
                    23,
                    22
                )
    ["fav-nums"] => Array
                    (
                        200,
                        300,
                        400
                    )
)
```

Comment: is this string names=bob;mike;sam&age=30;23;22&fav-nums=200;300;400 part of a url?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Its derived from a url (I get rid of everything before the `?` and then I am left with that string I have given)

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329) where form data wasn't structured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions to achieve this.

**Steps:**

1) Use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function, it will split your string into associative array.

2) Now loop over it and go for key values.

3) keys will be the required keys (names, age and fav-nums) and you want values to be array.

4) explode() the values with `;` and you will get required values.

**Working code:**

```
$str = "names=bob;mike;sam&age=30;23;22&fav-nums=200;300;400";
parse_str($str, $output);
$arr = [];
if (! empty($output)) {
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$key] = explode(';', $value);
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [names] => Array
        (
            [0] => bob
            [1] => mike
            [2] => sam
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 23
            [2] => 22
        )

    [fav-nums] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 400
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a direct method of creating the sub-arrays, but `parse_str()` will split the initial string by `&` and create the starting point, then process each element with `explode()` (and `array_walk()`) to create the sub-arrays.

```
$start = 'names=bob;mike;sam&age=30;23;22&fav-nums=200;300;400';
parse_str($start, $output);
array_walk($output, function ( &$data ) { $data = explode(";", $data); });
print_r($output);
```

which gives...

```
Array
(
    [names] => Array
        (
            [0] => bob
            [1] => mike
            [2] => sam
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 23
            [2] => 22
        )

    [fav-nums] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 400
        )

)
```

Comment: Can I ask, I know this is only 2 lines of code, but how many looks does this have? I know none are visible, but explode is a `n` loop, then `array_walk` is another `n` loop?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but there are always loops you aren't directly aware of - `parse_str()` must loop over the string as well as the two you mention.  But also PHP processes the source as a loop, the OP codes are probably executed in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **array_map** function in order to traverse the whole array as it boost up speed of your code. Also **parse_str** is always use in order to read **Query String** and convert it in array form.

```
    $text = 'names=bob;mike;sam&age=30;23;22&fav-nums=200;300;400';
    parse_str($text, $outputArray);
    $array = [];
    if(!empty($outputArray)) {
        $array = array_map(
                   function($v) { 
                       return explode(';', $v); 
                   }, $outputArray
        );

    }

echo"<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

The result shows

```
 Array
 (
  [names] => Array
    (
        [0] => bob
        [1] => mike
        [2] => sam
    )

 [age] => Array
    (
        [0] => 30
        [1] => 23
        [2] => 22
    )

 [fav-nums] => Array
    (
        [0] => 200
        [1] => 300
        [2] => 400
    )

)
```

Comment: This looks almost identical to the accepted answer, but without any explanation.

Comment: Hows its identical ? @NigelRen